# Customize how the reference numbers appear in the bibliography when using biblatex?

Tags: fonts, biblatex, formatting

I wish to customize the font for when printing the reference numbers (the to the left of all references, commonly surrounded by brackets) in the `biblatex` package. I hope that there is some command that you can simply renew, but I'm unable to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redefine the `labelnumberwidth` field format. (In my exampe I add bold formatting.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\textbf{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]